# URLSession not download in serial

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I am trying to create a serial URLSession so i can download largish files in a serial queue.  Ive been mucking around with this for day and am just getting more and more confused.

My immediate question is regarding getting my downloads to happen serially?

So far I've got the files downloading to my desired directory and can print the progress of the file through delegate method.  problem is if i download more than 1 file they happen concurrently which is not what I'm after.

I thought that by declaring the delegateQueue to nil this would be achieved??

```
lazy var downloadsSession: Foundation.URLSession = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "urlSessionConfig")
    let session = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    return session
}()
```

Then below, function to initiate download and delegate functions:

```
func startDownload(urlString: String, block: @escaping (_ downloading: Bool, _ url: String) -> Void) {

    let download = Download(url: urlString)
    let url =  URL(string: urlString)
    download.downloadTask = downloadsSession.downloadTask(with: url!)
    download.downloadTask!.resume()
    download.isDownloading = true
    activeDownloads[download.url] = download

    if download.isDownloading == true {
        block(true, urlString)
    }
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {

    if (downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString) != nil {

        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.cachesDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let cachesDirectory: String = path[0]
        let fileName  = URL(string: (downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString)!)?.lastPathComponent
        let destinationURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: cachesDirectory.appendingFormat("/Parse/PFFileCache/\(fileName!)"))


        print(destinationURL)

        // remove temp file
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        do {
            try fileManager.removeItem(at: destinationURL)
        } catch {
            // doesn't exist
        }
        do { // move to destinationURL
            try fileManager.copyItem(at: location as URL, to: destinationURL)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not copy file to disk: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }


        // remove the url from activeDownloads array
        if let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString {
            activeDownloads[url] = nil
            self.outerCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {


    if let downloadUrl = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString,
        let download = activeDownloads[downloadUrl] {
        download.progress = Float(totalBytesWritten)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
        //let totalSize = ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: totalBytesExpectedToWrite, countStyle: ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.binary)
        print("\(download) \(download.progress)")
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you care removing TEMPORARY files? Instead of copying it just use moveItem to move it from TMP to your destination directory

Comment: BTW you should move it out of the caches folder (not a subfolder of it) if you would like to keep it.

Comment: If they're all coming from the same server, you can set `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` in your session configuration.  Otherwise, what you're asking isn't possible (except by adding items to the session one at a time, which just replaces one set of problems with a different one).